# How to detect missing values if the dataframe has removed the missing rows already?

Tags: pandas, missing-data

I have a dataframe which contains time series data of 30 consecutive days, each day is supposed to contain data of 24 hours from 0 to 23, so there suppose to have 24*30 = 720 rows in the dataframe. However, there are some rows containing missing records of the column "Fooo" already being removed from the dataframe.

```
Index      | DATE(YYYY/MM/DD) |  Hour   |    Fooo
  0        | 2015/01/01       |    0    |     x 
  1        | 2015/01/01       |    1    |     xy 
  2        |     ...          |    ...  |     z 
  23       | 2015/01/01       |    23   |     z 

  24       | 2015/01/02       |    0    |     z 
  25       | 2015/01/02       |    2    |     bz 
  ...      |     ...          |    ...  |     z 
  46       | 2015/01/02       |    23   |     zz 
...
...
  680      | 2015/01/30       |    1    |     z 
  681      | 2015/01/30       |    3    |     bz 
  ...      |     ...          |    ...  |     z 
  701      | 2015/01/30       |    23   |     zz
```

I would like to rewrite the dataframe so that it contains full 720 rows, with missing values in the column "Fooo" being filled with "NA".

```
Index      | DATE(YYYY/MM/DD) |  Hour   |    Fooo
  0        | 2015/01/01       |    0    |     x 
  1        | 2015/01/01       |    1    |     xy 
  2        |     ...          |    ...  |     z 
  23       | 2015/01/01       |    23   |     z 

  24       | 2015/01/02       |    0    |     z 
  25       | 2015/01/02       |    1    |     NA   
  26       | 2015/01/02       |    2    |     bz 
  ...      |     ...          |    ...  |     z 
  47       | 2015/01/02       |    23   |     zz 
...
...
  690      | 2015/01/30       |    0    |     NA
  691      | 2015/01/30       |    1    |     z 
  692      | 2015/01/30       |    2    |     NA
  693      | 2015/01/30       |    3    |     bz 
  ...      |     ...          |    ...  |     z 
  719      | 2015/01/30       |    23   |     zz
```

How can I do that in pandas? I tried to create another dataframe with one column "Hour" like this:

```
Index      |  Hour   |    
  0        |    0    |    
  1        |    1    |    
  2        |    ...  |     
  23       |    23   |    

  24       |    0    |    
  25       |    1    |       
  26       |    2    |    
  ...      |     ...        
  47       |    23   |   
...
...
  690      |    0    |     
  691      |    1    |      
  692      |    2      
  693      |    3    |     
  ...      |         |    
  719      |    23   |
```

then outer join it with the original one, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create helper DataFrame by `product` and [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
from  itertools import product

df['DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)'].unique(), range(27))), 
                   columns=['DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)','Hour'])
df = df1.merge(df, how='left')
print (df.head(10))
  DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)  Hour Fooo
0       2015-01-01     0    x
1       2015-01-01     1   xy
2       2015-01-01     2  NaN
3       2015-01-01     3  NaN
4       2015-01-01     4  NaN
5       2015-01-01     5  NaN
6       2015-01-01     6  NaN
7       2015-01-01     7  NaN
8       2015-01-01     8  NaN
9       2015-01-01     9  NaN
```

Or create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for append missing rows:

```
df['DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)'])

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)'].unique(), range(27)], 
                                     names=['DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)','Hour'])
df = df.set_index(['DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)','Hour']).reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df.head(10))
  DATE(YYYY/MM/DD)  Hour Fooo
0       2015-01-01     0    x
1       2015-01-01     1   xy
2       2015-01-01     2  NaN
3       2015-01-01     3  NaN
4       2015-01-01     4  NaN
5       2015-01-01     5  NaN
6       2015-01-01     6  NaN
7       2015-01-01     7  NaN
8       2015-01-01     8  NaN
9       2015-01-01     9  NaN
```